# Input string was not in a correct format in datalist control

Tags: c#

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]);
```

> after compliling error is Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Add .ToString() after [e.Item.ItemIndex]. So it looks like this: [e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use `Convert.ToInt32` with `string` input, it will only return valid result (and not exception) if all the characters of the `string` are numbers with total value limited to `int.MinValue` to `int.MaxValue`.

Firstly, to ensure that the input is in the `string` format, change `DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]` with `DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString()`, something like this

```
string itemStr = DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
```

and secondly, to ensure that the `string` is the the right format, try to parse it using `int.TryParse`. Only if the argument passes `int.TryParse` that you are safe to perform `Convert.ToInt32` to it

```
int id;
if (int.TryParse(itemStr, out id)){
    //do something with id
} else { 
    //Parse fails, do something
}
```

See if it helps.